# Using unset vs. setting a variable to empty

Tags: bash, variables, syntax

I'm currently writing a bash testing framework, where in a test function, both standard bash tests (`[[`) as well as predefined matchers can be used. Matchers are wrappers to '[[' and besides returning a return code, set some meaningful message saying what was expected.

Example:

```
string_equals() {
    if [[ ! $1 = $2 ]]; then
            error_message="Expected '$1' to be '$2'."

            return 1
    fi
}
```

So, when a matcher is used, and it fails, only then an error_message is set.

Now, at some point later, I test whether the tests succeeded. If it succeeded, I print the expectation in green, if it failed in red.

Furthermore, there may be an error_message set, so I test if a message exists, print it, and then unset it (because the following test may not set an `error_message`):

```
if [[ $error_message ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$error_message"

    unset -v error_message
fi
```

Now my question is, if it is better to unset the variable, or to just set it to '', like

```
error_message=''
```

Which one is better? Does it actually make a difference? Or maybe should I have an additional flag indicating that the message was set?

Comment: If you never compare `error_message` with anything else, I'd say it doesn't matter. However, I think you want `[[ $error_message ]]`, otherwise you are testing that the literal string "error_message" exists.

Comment: @chepner Yeah, was a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Mostly you don't see a difference, unless you are using `set -u`:

```
/home/user1> var=""
/home/user1> echo $var

/home/user1> set -u
/home/user1> echo $var

/home/user1> unset var
/home/user1> echo $var
-bash: var: unbound variable
```

So really, it depends on how you are going to test the variable.

I will add that my preferred way of testing if it is set is:

```
[[ -n $var ]]  # True if the length of $var is non-zero
```

or

```
[[ -z $var ]]  # True if zero length
```

Comment: `var=` is not "not set". It's just an unquoted empty string. In addition to `set -u`, bash's various forms of parameter expansion can also distinguish between unset and null values: `${foo:bar}` expands to "bar" when `foo` is unset, but "" when `foo` is null, while `${foo:-bar}` expands to "bar" if foo is unset or null.

Comment: `[[ -n $var ]]` is false if `var` is set to the empty string.

Comment: if you use 'declare -p' to check for variable 'existence' then var= will show 'declare -- var=""' you must use unset to get rid of it, of course if its a readonly variable then you cant get rid of it of course. Furthermore, if you var=something inside a function, you wont have to worry about getting rid of it if you use "local var=value" be careful though, because "declare var=value" is also local.In the case of declare you have to explicitly set it global using "declare -g var=value", without declare you have to explicitly set it to be local using "local".Global vars are only erased /w unset.

Comment: @osirisgothra:  good point about local variables.   Of course generally it is best to declare (or localise) all variables in a function so that it is encapsulated.

Comment: @chepner should be `${foo-bar}` instead of `${foo:bar}`. test for yourself: `unset a; echo ">${a:-foo}-${a:foo}-${a-foo}<"`

Comment: @LiviuChircu - In [GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)] I get [ >foo--foo< ].

Comment: `[[ -n $var ]]` will not return true or false, but raise the `unbound variable` error, if `set -u` is used and `$var` is unset.

Answer (score 19):

As has been said, using unset is different with arrays as well

```
$ foo=(4 5 6)

$ foo[2]=

$ echo ${#foo[*]}
3

$ unset foo[2]

$ echo ${#foo[*]}
2
```

Answer (score 2):

So, by unset'ting the array index 2, you essentially remove that element in the array and decrement the array size (?).

I made my own test..

```
foo=(5 6 8)
echo ${#foo[*]}
unset foo
echo ${#foo[*]}
```

Which results in..

```
3
0
```

So just to clarify that unset'ting the entire array will in fact remove it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above, here is a simple test:

```
isunset() { [[ "${!1}" != 'x' ]] && [[ "${!1-x}" == 'x' ]] && echo 1; }
isset()   { [ -z "$(isunset "$1")" ] && echo 1; }
```

Example:

```
$ unset foo; [[ $(isunset foo) ]] && echo "It's unset" || echo "It's set"
It's unset
$ foo=     ; [[ $(isunset foo) ]] && echo "It's unset" || echo "It's set"
It's set
$ foo=bar  ; [[ $(isunset foo) ]] && echo "It's unset" || echo "It's set"
It's set
```